# Tablas HTML en SHELL unix

Tags: html, shell

Quiero enviar un mail con una tabla HTML la cual creo en una Shell, pero al enviarla no me genera la tabla solo me genera el encabezado y los datos. Dejo el código de la Shell:

```
(
echo "To: correo@correo.cl"
echo "Subject: MENSAJE DE PRUEBA"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
echo 
echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<table>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th>ORIGEN</th>"
echo "<th>TIPO</th>"
echo "<th>CANTIDAD</th>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<td>$esac</td>"
echo "<td>ARCHIVO</td>"
echo "<td>1679748</td>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "</table>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
echo
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Comment: Todo funciona bien para mi, excepto no hay nada donde tiene "$esac" (por supuesto.)  Tal vez hay algo en este variable que causa el problema?  Que pasa si usas texto literal en ese lugar?

Comment: @Duston he probado como dices y sigue el mismo problema, no genera la tabla.

Comment: Es decir no genera las lineas alrededor de las palabras? o las palabras no son rectas?  No son filas ni columnas?

Comment: @Duston lo solucione colocando lo siguiente: 
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="666633"> y le saque la etiqueta body.

Comment: Muy bien.  Me alegre que encuentres la respuesta

Comment: @Ricardo Por favor agrega la solución que encontraste como respuesta y acéptala una vez hayan pasado 48 horas. De esa manera el sistema reconocerá esta pregunta como resuelta y podrá ser de utilidad a personas con problemas similares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione colocando lo siguiente:

```
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="666633">
```

y le saque la etiqueta body.